# Moshi generateAdapter not working with list of JSON objects

Tags: android, json, retrofit, okhttp, moshi

I'm trying to create a small `Android` app using `Moshi` and I have the following `JSON`:

```
{
   "drinks":[
      {
         "strCategory":"Ordinary Drink"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Cocktail"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Milk \/ Float \/ Shake"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Other\/Unknown"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Cocoa"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Shot"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Coffee \/ Tea"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Homemade Liqueur"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Punch \/ Party Drink"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Beer"
      },
      {
         "strCategory":"Soft Drink \/ Soda"
      }
   ]
}
```

and I have created two data classes for parsing the previous `JSON`:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class DrinksCategory(@Json(name = "strCategory")val strCategory: String)
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class DrinksCategories(@Json(name = "drinks") val drinkCategories: List<DrinksCategory>)
```

However, when I run my app I see the following error:

> Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response for method DrinksService.getDrinksCategories

Is there anything that I'm missing here? Anything else I should do in order to automatically have the adapter generated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out the problem was a missing `suspend` keyword in the method that would make this API request in the `Retrofit` service